# Realistic Shadow Casting On Widget In Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, shadow, light

I want to achieve simulation of flickering effect or realistic shadows casted by natural neon lights. Something like the picture:
[Glowing Square With Two Light Sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZaFF.png)

I have tried boxshadow in container boxdecoration, but it generates a box-shaped uniform shadow/light around the container, but not simulating distinct light source casting on the widget.

I have also looked for alternative, such as achieving the effect using AE, and then import it as assets in Lottie, but I am not a designer to know how to do it.

How should I achieve the effect by dart?

Comment: instead of `BoxDecoration` you can write a custom `Decorarion` class that you can use directly as `Container.decoration` or `DecoratedBox.decoration` properties

Comment: I think the Decoration class in here works well if I want to customize the border? For mimicking the casting of light which produces layers of lights and shadows beyond the boundaries of the container, it seems customizable shadow instead of BoxShadow would be more of favour.

maybe what I need indeed is a customize Shadow class that allows me to produce irregular shape shadow that position relatively to the targeted container, works by using Stack. I did have tried to do so, but the container containing some Shadow could not align properly with the main container.

Comment: I mean you need a custom `Decorstion` class - something like `class NeonDecoration extends Decoration { ...`